# Записать в список выполненной программы и вычленить максимум

Tags: python

у меня появился вопрос. Если программа выводит много результатов можно ли из него вычленить одно максимальное число. Я пробовал списки что то не хочет. Программа представлена ниже.

```
list=[]
s='0'+('1'*61)+('2'*50)+('3'*18)+'0'
while not '00' in s:
    s=s.replace('01','210',1)
    s = s.replace('02', '3101', 1)
    s = s.replace('03', '2012', 1)
maximum = (list)
print(maximum)
```

Но, она выводит пустой список.

Comment: а кто лист заполнял?

Comment: ну я же хочу что бы код его заполнял

Comment: У вас все значения списка в переменной s. Чтобы вывести итог нужно присвоить list = s. а уж потом вывести max(list)